# Starting Intent From MainActivity, how to change content on Mainactivity after returning from Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, call

on the MainActivity I have a textview with a number in it, it show's the played levels. The game ist called by an intent, after leaving the intent, you cann see the mainscreen again. How can I update the mainscreen?
Every time i have to restart the game to see the actual level?
thanks

Comment: declare one public static variable and keep updating that variable

Comment: or post respective code so that I can edit and resolve

Answer (score 2):

You can use shared preferances to store your game level. Store the level by shared preferances and just retreive from that.

Comment: whats that? :D and how to implement it?

Comment: the below link is an examplw of shared preferances    http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/